# Javascript Delete items from array that exists in another array without mutating for reducers

Tags: javascript, redux

I have following two arrays

```
let a = ["Hello", "bye", "good morning", "test"];
let b = ["Hello", "test"];
```

How can i delete items that exists in array b from array a(without mutation)? The resultant array should look like:-

```
["bye", "good morning"];
```

Comment: Please specify: is `["bye", "good morning"]` the final value in a, or a new array c.  "Resultant" implies c, but "delete" implies a.

Comment: New array without mutation

Comment: have you looked into the underscore.js library. There are very useful method there!

Comment: No way without any library?

Comment: So clone the array or use reduce/filter

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I dont want to use for loops above filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

filter() and some()

```
let a = ["Hello", "bye", "good morning", "test"],
    b = ["Hello", "test"],
    c = a.filter( e => !b.some( i => i===e))
```